# How to do Sequel query chaining with WITH and OR

Tags: ruby, sequel

I'm trying to build a query in Sequel that's causing me a bit of trouble.

Basically I have several hashes, each containing several conditions.  The conditions in each hash need to AND within themselves and OR within each group of conditions.

For example:

```
conditions = [
  { :id => 123, :published => true },
  { :id => 456, :published => false }
]
```

Should generate:

```
SELECT * FROM item WHERE ((id = 123 AND published = true) OR (id = 456 AND published = false))
```

I have:

```
conditions.each do |condition|
  query = query.where(condition)
end
```

This will AND everything together, so:

```
conditions.each do |condition|
  query = query.or(condition)
end
```

Throws an error because the OR requires more than one condition in the query.  Other than popping the first condition into a `where` and the rest into an `or`, which would be a bit ugly:

```
query.where(condition.first)
conditions[1..-1].each do |condition|
  query = query.or(condition)
end
```

Is there a nicer way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing to do is just to gather the results of individual queries into an array which is the same as you would get OR-ing together all the AND clauses in one query:

```
results = conditions.map{|c| query.where(c).all}.flatten
```